# Blackberry app version update deletes persistent store object on some devices

Tags: blackberry, persistent-storage

I have a Blackberry app that stores an object in the persistent store. After updating the app, it is supposed to read the existing value from the persistent store, if any, and continue to use that value. This works on some devices, but does not work on others. I tested on several devices running OS version 7, all of which work as expected. However on a device using version 5 and another using version 6, the object is no longer readable in the persistent store.

This is the case even if I don't change anything about the app other than the version number. Same exact class/object being saved & loaded from the persistent store, and same object ID used to access it.

The process I'm following to reproduce this is:

1. Completely delete the app & all it's data using the command line.
2. Load a version of the app, by downloading a .jad file from a browser, verify that it stores data in the persistent store.
3. While the app is running in the background, load a later version via browser download of the .jad file.
4. After downloading the later version, the system asks if I want to replace the previous version, and I confirm that I do.
5. The system loads the new version, and prompts that I must reboot for the change to take effect. I select "Reboot".
6. Device reboots. The later version is running but cannot read the object from the persistent store.

A device on which I can consistently reproduce this issue is a Blackberry 9800 (Torch) running 6.0 Bundle 2647.

As mentioned above this only happens on some, not all, devices, which makes me think something other than a coding bug may be going on here.

Anyone have ideas about this issue or how to debug it further?

Answer (score 0):

Peculiar case.

Are you sure the persistent storage is being committed? Something similar generally occurs for me when data has been stored in the storage but not committed. If that is the case, and you load the older version, store some data and reboot your device, the data will not be stored in persistence.

You mentioned that the app is still running in the background when you load a later version. You may want to check whether `commit()` gets executed or not.

Comment: Thank you for the excellent thought Abhishek. I checked this by adding a reboot of the older version and making sure it could still read the stored data after the reboot, before installing the new version. Unfortunately the new version still cannot read the value so I suspect something about the install process clears the value.